# async org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, async

I have a lot of org files in emacs 27.1 so when I do an agenda listing for the week it takes about 20seconds. Is there a nice way to do this in the background? I've put together the following function and it sort of works. The *Org Agenda* buffer that it shows in the finish lambda is blank, but the agenda.org file is correct but it's just an org file not the special Org Agenda buffer.

```
(defun async-org-agenda-list()
  (interactive)
  (async-start

   ;; start
   (lambda ()
     (setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/" "~/org/projects"))
     (org-agenda-list)
     (switch-to-buffer "*Org Agenda*")
     (append-to-file (point-min) (point-max) "~/agenda.org")
     )

   ;; finish
   (lambda (msg)
     (message "done")
     )
   )
  )
```

Is there a way to do the Agenda in the background and display it in the Org Agenda buffer in the correct mode?

Comment: have you tried calling `(org-agenda)` rather than list?

Comment: @zzkt (org-agenda) just pops up a menu, I used (org-agenda-list) so that I get the results for the week which is what is taking so long to do with all my tasks (378 TODOS last count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SECOND EDIT

A solution that also fixes the links has been posted/implemented [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async/issues/145#issuecomment-902500105).

Thanks Thierry!

EDIT

Okay, so you can fix it by adding the following two lines before just before the `(goto-char (point-max))` in the `async-when-done` function (see the comment to this answer also):

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(replace-string "#" "")
```

I will send a mail about it to the emacs-devel mailing list.

END EDIT

Nice idea!

The following answer works for simple org files. However, the `async` API seems to error on some more complex org files (bug?). Anyway, would be nice to hear back how it works on your files.

Okay, then here follows the code:

```lisp
(defun map-text-properties (props)
  (let ((plist (caddr props)))
    (while plist
      (put-text-property (1+ (nth 0 props))
                         (1+ (nth 1 props))
                         (car plist)
                         (cadr plist))
      (setq plist (cddr plist)))
    (when props
      (map-text-properties (nthcdr 3 props)))))

(async-start
 ;; What to do in the child process
 (lambda ()
   (setq org-agenda-files '("~/spacemacs/diary.org"))
   (org-agenda-list)
   (buffer-string))

 ;; What to do when it finishes
 (lambda (result)
   (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Org Agenda*")
   (insert (car result))
   (map-text-properties (cdr result))
   (org-agenda-mode)))
```

The `map-text-properties` properties function is required because the *async API* returns the text object as a list. There is probably an easier way to convert the list back into a text object (but I did not look very much into that).

Comment: I have debugged it a little, and I have found that the problem is that the `async` sentinel function (`async-when-done`) is not able to `read` the returned string. However, this is not due to the `async` API, because when I print my *Org Agenda* buffer (using `(buffer-string)`) and then try to `read` the output, I already get the same error. But at least this method works, if you 'dismiss' the text properties. Also there must be a workaround, `e.g.` to first replace all `#` in the async process buffer, before `read`ing it.

Comment: I have opened an issue/notification/suggestion about it [at emacs-async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async/issues/145)

Comment: That worked. I did have to put the two lines in my async-when-done function like you. Thanks. It's getting other tags in my list like REDUNDANT. Also I cannot click on any of the agenda items to take me there. So all the links are gone. Is there a way to keep the links intact?

Comment: Also the colour formatting is off. Other than that it works great. I can continue using my emacs as it's getting my agenda ready.

Comment: Ah, the link and color formatting work fine here (i.e. jumping to the original location works). So how far is the color formatting off? Because I was surprised that I has to put the `1+`'s into the `put-text-property` form. Maybe you can fix it by removing them? If not, then maybe open a chat, or contact me on the [Spacemacs gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs) (because Stack exchange warns that comments are not meant for long discussions). If we find a solution then we can edit the answer again here...

Comment: Another (cleaner) solution was proposed [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async/issues/145), but unfortunately it turned out to not work fully as expected. However, the information given there might still be interesting/valuable/relevant.